# GWT 2.1 and the Codehaus Maven plugin

Tags: maven-2, gwt, maven-plugin

Has anybody managed to get the release of GWT 2.1 to work with the Codehaus Maven plugin?

http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/

The 1.2 stable release does not seem to work.  I found a version called 1.3.2 here in the SVN maven repo from GWT

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/2.1.0/gwt/maven/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt-maven-plugin/1.3.2.google/

But when I run it I get the following error message...

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.3.2.google:compile
>   (default) on project pipeda-webapp:
>   Execution default of goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.3.2.google:compile
>   failed. NullPointerException -> [Help
>   1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gwt-maven-plugin 2.1.0 is in maven central now

Answer (score 3):

With

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>gwt-maven.snapshots</id>
        <url>http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

and

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</plugin>
```

I believe I have it working with GWT 2.1.

You will get this warning:

```
[WARNING] You're project declares dependency on gwt-user 2.1.0. This plugin is designed for version 2.1-SNAPSHOT
```

but compilation still completes.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the codehause maven plugin 1.2 doesn't work with GWT-2.1.0.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MGWT-228?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

So apparently we have to 'wait for the snapshots'

Comment: The new version of the codehause Maven GWT plugin has been release: http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [complete & working Maven configuration for GWT 2.5.0-rc1 & Google App Engine using gwt-maven-plugin](https://github.com/loxal/Epvin/blob/master/pom.xml) to build the app.